# Как сделать всплывающее окно в Android

Tags: java, android

Как cделать такое вспливающее окно? Идет анимация появления снизу. Окно сидит внизу. AlertDialog дает иной результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Называется Bottom Sheet, пример реализации можно найти по первой [ссылке](https://habr.com/ru/post/309200/) в поиске

Comment: полагаю, что это [snackbar](https://material.io/components/snackbars)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все что касается UI тут вообще мало каких-либо стандартов.

Вы можете реализовать подобную штуку разными способами:

- Вы можете в XML нарисовать свою View и сделать ей `visibility = gone` и показывать ее в нужной вам ситуации.
- Вы можете создать [Dialog Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=ru). Вот [тут](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/180-urok-110-android-3-fragments-dialogfragment-dialog.html) есть урок на эту тему.
- Вы можете реализовать [SnackBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar). Вот [тут](https://javadevblog.com/primer-ispol-zovaniya-snackbar-v-android-sozdaem-kastomny-j-snackbar.html) пример.
- Вы даже можете создать новый Fragment/Activity с прозрачным фоном и UI в котором будет только такой макет. Но это наверн излишне.
- Если вам нужно выезжать снизу, то рекомендую глянуть на [BottomSheet](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427) или опять в том же XML написать View которая будет выезжать анимированно (но это сложнее). Можно глянуть в сторону [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout). Крутая [кодлаба](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/motion-layout/#0) по MotionLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут хороший видеогайд по созданию своего `dialog` на основе своего `View` в XML. [Custom dialog box 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67j1yIFa48s). Очень все подробно.
Что касается анимации то вот тут хорошее видео рассказывающее как это работает [Анимация view элементов](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZN8MBxUgUkE&list=PLyfVjOYzujugap6Rf3ETNKkx4v9ePllNK&index=22) и вот тут если текстовая версия так же подробно [еще Анимация view элементов](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/tweenanimation.php). Если хотите уж совсем крутую анимацию то вот про интерполяцию `android:interpolator` [Интерполяторы](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/interpolator.php)